# openldap noopsrch overlay with pythons ldap3 search

Tags: python, ldap, openldap

We use the https://ltb-project.org/documentation/openldap-noopsrch.html overlay on openldap.

It gives you the number of entries in each catalog without having to browse all.

example show `-e '!1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.18'` controltype to ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -x -H 'ldap://localhost:389' -D 'cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com' 
 -w secret -b 'dc=my-domain,dc=com' \
 '(objectClass=*)' -e '!1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.18'
```

I use the python3 ldap3: https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searches.html

Any tips/examples on how to implement this?

Comment: (I can't test right now so I leave this as a comment) - I guess you can use the function [build_control()](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/blob/v2.9.1/ldap3/protocol/controls.py#L30), for example : `from ldap3.protocol.controls import build_control`, `controls = [build_control(oid='1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.18', criticality=True, value=None)]`, and then `c.search(base, filter, scope, controls=controls)` where `c` is a `Connection` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EricLavault answer I managed to fix this:

```
c.search(base, filter, scope, controls=[
  build_control(oid='1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.18',
  criticality=True,
  value=None)
])
```

c.result then holds a controls dict:

```
{
 'result': 0, 'description': 'success', 'dn': '', 
 'message': '', 'referrals': None, 'type': 'searchResDone', 
 'controls': {
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.18': {'description': '', 
    'criticality': False, 
    'value': b'0\x0b\x02\x01\x00\x02\x03\x01\xf0\xac\x02\x01\x00'
  }
}
```

The format of value is described here:

https://ltb-project.org/documentation/openldap-noopsrch.html#usage

```
>>> v = b'0\x0b\x02\x01\x00\x02\x03\x01\xf0\xac\x02\x01\x00'
>>> vh = hex(int.from_bytes(v,'big'))
>>> vhl = [f"0x{vh[i:i+2]}" for i in range(2, len(vh), 2)]
>>> vhl
['0x30', '0x0b', '0x02', '0x01', '0x00', '0x02', '0x03', '0x01', '0xf0', '0xac', '0x02', '0x01', '0x00']
# org count length is the 7th hex from msb in vhl (it can have another position if the response have any kind of error)
>>> orglen = int(vhl[6], 16)
>>> orgcount = vhl[7:7+orglen]    
>>> orgcount
['0x01', '0xf0', '0xac']
>>> c = '0x'
# merge orgcount hex
>>> for o in orgcount:
...     c += f"{int(o, 16):02x}"
...
>>> c = int(c, 16) # convert back to dec
>>> c
127148
```

Checked by counting the objects returned given the same base,scope and filter, only it took 27sec to parse while this took 0.24sec